# how to create same rtf output as listing output in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create same output as listing output but when i sent the output to ods rtf/pdf/html output is changing i.e aligning to left side . Is there any way to create same
output as that of listing output.

Required Output:

http://i776.photobucket.com/albums/yy47/hemanth2317/Datasetrequiredoutput.jpg

Rtf O/P:

http://i776.photobucket.com/albums/yy47/hemanth2317/RtfOutput.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify elements of RTF output, you would need to create a style in `PROC TEMPLATE` with the appropriate changes based on what you're interested in changing.

Additionally, some elements might be changeable by PROC options.  For example, `PROC REPORT` has a `CENTER` option to allow it to be centered in the page.

See [Pretty Please: Making RTF Output Pretty with SAS](http://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2013/IB/PharmaSUG-2013-IB08.pdf) and other similar RTF output papers for more details.